chess.com dosn't apply fide rule?
I was talking about the draw set, in FIDE
9.3 The game is drawn, upon a correct claim by a player having the move, if:
9.3.2 the last 50 moves by each player have been completed without the movement of any pawn and without any capture.
9.2 The game is drawn upon a correct claim by the player having the move, when the same
position, for at least the third time (not necessarily by a repetition of moves):
9.2.2 Positions are considered the same if and only if the same player has the move, pieces of the same kind and color occupy the same squares and the possible moves of all the pieces of both players are the same. Thus, positions are not the same if:
9.6 If one or both of the following occur(s) then the game is drawn:
9.6.1 the same position has appeared, as in 9.2.2 at least five times.
9.6.2 any series of at least 75 moves have been made by each player without the movement of any pawn and without any capture. If the last move resulted in checkmate, that shall take precedence.
But on chess.com, at 50 move and 3 repetition, the game is automatically a draw, normally, at 50 move and 3 repetition we can claim a draw, and the automatic draw is at 75 or 5
Is it the same on Lichess? Are there other rules that don't apply on chess.com?

Lichess you can configure automatic draw claim in settings (you can pick claim draw automatically, automatically in time trouble or always manually).
